# How to fix a misbehaving mirror?

Tags: apt, mirrors

I use the mirrors:// syntax for my `sources.list` file:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

But recently one mirror has consistently been running the wrong hashes:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.portafixe.com/ubuntu/archive/dists/focal-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/62d1b566cf8f5c45def53f37ff0dfc4edaa7cf94f87de14dcfe0207ce4fea506  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:887780 [weak]
    - SHA256:62d1b566cf8f5c45def53f37ff0dfc4edaa7cf94f87de14dcfe0207ce4fea506
    - SHA1:f396806d9de01fd941289493542fc77f133d57b0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ade39adc4d14dfe01b018bcb98bbeee7 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:15c5e0c831cd13f13b975a9db2703f33e95f3363ec16c3ff96fe10b4b501d3cc
    - SHA1:24856eff3daf9f1e54844b9b5fe04229b6332687 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2f88f776ebfb50bf60d076f1ca8f7056 [weak]
    - Filesize:5315 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 16:00:38 +0000
   Release file created at: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 13:12:34 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It also returns the wrong hashes for the downloaded deb files too.  apt(-get) correctly ignores them, but it means I have to run extra commands (with --fix-missing) to do an upgrade.

I tried messaging the user responsible for that mirror on launchpad.net but haven't gotten a reply. Is there anyone else to contact to try and fix this misbehaving mirror?